# Regex to extract values from Insert Query

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have this query

```
INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz);
```

I'm using the following method to extract the values alone

```
public String extractValues(String queryLine){
    return queryLine.substring(queryLine.indexOf('(') + 1,queryLine.lastIndexOf(')'));
}
```

But later I realised that the `Insert query` can take the form of following,

```
INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,bbb,ccc);
```

How can I extract the values now?

I'm thinking maybe `regex` is the way to go and split to occur on `),(` but that does not seem right.What if one of the values has those? Therefore am not sure.

Please guide.

Case I'm struggling to handle

```
INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc);
```

**Required output:** `xxx,yyy,zzz and aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc`

**P.S:** The commas in between the values does not matter

Comment: I think the problem is with `'bb),(b'` instead of `'bb(,)b'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize a certain pattern in language that support char literals (that has to be excluded from the recognition) is solved generally with this scheme:

- find and substitute the pattern you're searching inside char literals, for example 'b),(bb' should become 'b###bb'
- perform recognition on the modified string
- restore the pattern inside char literals, so 'b###b' should return 'b),(bb'

I don't know how to accomplish this with a single statement or a single regular expression. Just for sake of this argument I write the following code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValuesListParse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String stmt = " INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb),(b',ccc),(aaa,bbb,ccc); ";
    System.out.printf("%s\n", stmt);

    //extract values list
    stmt = stmt.split("(?i)\\s+values\\s*\\(|\\);")[1];
    System.out.printf("values list: %s\n", stmt);

    // identify pattern between '' (char literal) and replace it with another pattern: the 2nd group is what we want 
    /* UPDATE modified regexp from ('.*)(\\)\\,\\()(.*') to ('\\w*)(\\)\\,\\()+(\\w*') to manage multiple literals containig the pattern */
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("('\\w*)(\\)\\,\\()+(\\w*')").matcher(stmt);
    while (m.find()) {
        stmt = stmt.substring(0, m.start(2)) + "###" + stmt.substring(m.end(2), stmt.length());
        System.out.printf("values list with pattern subst inside char literal: %s\n", stmt);
    }

    // split multiple values
    String[] multiValues = stmt.split("\\)\\,\\(");

    // adjust char literal
    for (int i = 0; i < multiValues.length ; i++) {
        multiValues[i] = multiValues[i].replaceAll("###", "),(");
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiValues));

   }
}
```

Comment: @Magesh wait I've to do some improvements it doesn't work for example on this ` INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb),(b',ccc),(aaa,'zz),(z',ccc);`. Maybe mixing this and the @Mario's solution it could be perfect :)

Comment: @Magesh now works also for this `INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa, 'bb),(b', 'cc),(c'),(aaa,'zz),(z',ccc);`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write your code so:

```
public String[] extractValues(String queryLine){
    String valuesRaw = queryLine.substring(queryLine.indexOf("VALUES(") + 7,  queryLine.lastIndexOf(");"));
    return valuesRaw.split("\\),\\(");
}
```

And all should work as now, except that you have to handle an array of strings instead of a plain string.

No need of regexps.

**UPDATE**

You could check if your insert string contains sequences that could broke the method.

Here is a test class containing the enanched code:

```
public class Test {

    public String[] extractValues(String queryLine){
        String valuesRaw = queryLine.substring(queryLine.indexOf("VALUES(") + 7,  queryLine.lastIndexOf(");"));

        if (valuesRaw.indexOf("),(") > -1) {
            valuesRaw = valuesRaw.replaceAll("'([^\\(\\)]*)\\),\\(([^\\(\\)]*)'", "'$1#SEPARATOR#$2'");
            String[] values = valuesRaw.split("\\),\\(");
            int i = 0;
            for (String value : values) {
                if (value.indexOf("#SEPARATOR#") > -1) {
                    values[i] = value.replace("#SEPARATOR#", "),(");
                }
                i++;
            }
            return values;
        } else {
            return valuesRaw.split("\\),\\(");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        String[] allQueryStrings = new String[] {
                "INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz);",
                "INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,bbb,ccc);",
                "INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc);",
                "INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb),(b',ccc);"
        };

        for (String queryString : allQueryStrings) {

            System.out.println(queryString);

            for (String values : t.extractValues(queryString)) {
                System.out.println(values);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that this will fail for inputs such as `(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc);` . That was my problem actually. For example refer here-> http://ideone.com/awRPuU

Comment: This is a regexps `valuesRaw.split("\\),\\(")` :)

Comment: @Aris2World am sorry I dont get what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Aris2World :) right, but is not intended to handle all the solution, just the split.

Comment: @MageshKumaar actually it works with *(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc);*, the problem is with *(xxx,yyy,zzz),(aaa,'bb),(b',ccc);*

Comment: @Mario good work I like learned something new on replaceAll using groups. Maybe I could rewrite my proposal code in this way. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try the regular expression `\(.*?,.*?,.*?\)`
EDIT: Try regex `\(.+?,.+?,.+?\)`

Comment: This doesnt work for the following case `(aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc)`

Comment: It works...You are trying to get the values inside the brackets right?Try it in notepad++

Comment: If my input is this -> `(10,20,30),(40,'aa(,)a','zzz')` 
My intended output-> `10,20,30 and 40,'aa(,)a','zzz'` and the regex above will break one of the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `\([^\)]+\)` and find all matches.

Comment: What if one of the value is `(aaa,'bb(,)b',ccc)` ?

Comment: You did not mention that parentheses are allowed as characters. In this case you should avoid using regex. Instead, you need to iterate through the string character by character and count "opening parenthesis - closing parenthesis". A closing parenthesis that leads to a count of 0 ends a part of the string.

Comment: If even non-matching parentheses in between are possible, you need to exactly specify you grammar before you start.

Comment: I did mention that `split to occur on ),( .... What if one of the values has those?` . Is any other way to handle this. I have an idea to proceed like if these characters `),(` is going to occur between quotes -> `'` so can I do something with that